# Ambiguous operator precedence, please explain why operator predence is not followed here?

Tags: c

```
x = y = z = 1;
z = ++x||++y&&++z;
```

operator precedence is as follows --

```
(pre-increment) > && > ||
```

so answer should be--

```
1.  2||2 && 2
2.  2||1
3.  1

print x,y,z should be 2,2,1
```

but, answer is 2,1,1.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @aaronman I mentioned the precedence as well.!

Comment: Ssee [Operator Precedence vs Order of Evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5473107/62576).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expressions with logical operators `&&` and `||` evaluate left to right:

> **C99, Section 6.5.14-4** Unlike the bitwise `|` operator, the `||` operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; there is a sequence point after the evaluation of the first operand. If the first operand compares unequal to `0`, the second operand is not evaluated.

Since `x++` is not zero, the expression short-circuits evaluation of everything to the right of `||`, including their side effects. That's why only `x++` is evaluated, so `x` becomes `2`. The remaining variables stay at `1`, as they should.

Comment: Since && has a higher precedence, it would be evaluated _first,_ no? So the ++y and ++z should execute.

Comment: @paxdiablo you might be right about the precedence, but I agree it's not UB

Comment: @aaronman, I suggest you look into Annex C of the standard, it's clear on what the sequence points are.

Comment: Exactly, thats what happening.!
I)so,, correct me if i am wrong, once short circuit of evaluation has happened , rest part is left as it is?
II) can you give a couple of examples in which this short circuit evaluation, or in other words, "condition for short circuit of evaluation"?

Comment: @paxdiablo then you should correct the answer in the [exact duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521607/precedence-of-logical-operators-in-c) because it says nothing about UB

Comment: @aaron, that's because it's _not_ an exact duplicate. There is no assignment to `c/z` in that question, hence it's _not_ UB. This question, with the assignment, is UB.

Comment: @paxdiablo the printf statement prints out a,b and c implying that a was assigned even if they didn't write it that way, I think I understand the UB after the standards quote btw

Comment: @aaronman, `a` was modified by the pre-incr in that question and that's okay since it only modified it _once._ `a = ++a ...` would have been UB but not the code as given. You can _assume_ assignment was done if you wish but it's neither _in_ the question, nor necessary for the changed `a` or `printf` to make sense. But we're getting off-track here, so I'll shut up now :-)

Comment: das, I'd suggest fixing up that "expressions evaluate left to right" bit, While that's true for some (including the current case `a || b`), it's not the case for all expressions. C99 6.5/3 states that evaluation of subexpressions (and side effects) is unspecified.

Comment: @paxdiablo You are right, the left-to-right statement was too general. I edited to clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Precedence is not the same as order of evaluation. Precedence simply determines what operands and operators belong together. The exact order of evaluation is unspecified **except** with the logical operators, which are evaluated in strict left-to-right order to enable short-circuiting.

So because `&&` has higher precedence, the variables are first grouped as follows:

```
(++x) || (++y && ++z)
```

Then, following left-to-right order, `++x` is evaluated. Given that `++x` is true, it is known that the entire expression is true. So expression evaluation is short-circuited.  `(++y && ++z)` never gets evaluated.  Hence y and z never get incremented.

Comment: You may want to clarify that the exact order of evaluation is unspecified except for short-circuiting operators `||` and `&&`, in which case it's strictly left-to-right.

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight. I have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

There's no sequence point in the expression:

```
z = ++x || ++y && ++z;
```

between the pre-increment of `z` and assignment to `z`.

So, if the `++z` is actually evaluated, that puts you instantly into undefined behaviour territory and *anything* can happen. You are not permitted to modify the same object twice without an intervening sequence point. Annex C (from C99) lists all the sequence points and the controlling one here is following a full-expression (the *entire* calculation and assignment).

`6.5 Expressions /2` states:

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.

However, given your initial value of `x` as 1, the `++z` part of the expression is not evaluated, in this particular case. That doesn't make the expression itself any less dangerous since it will invoke UB in the case where the starting point is `x == -1` and `y != -1`.

In this case, the controlling part of the standard is `6.5.14 Logical OR operator /4`:

> Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator **guarantees left-to-right evaluation;** there is a sequence point after the evaluation of the first operand. **If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.**

So, the `++x` is evaluated first and, because it evaluates to not-zero, `++y && ++z` is never evaluated. `x` is incremented to `2` and `z` is set to the "truthy" value of that, or `1`, `y` remains untouched at `1`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, he's modifying `z` twice with no intervening sequence point, the pre-incr and the assignment. Without the assignment, it would be an order-of-evaluation problem. _With_ that, it's UB.

Comment: Ah yes - I looked at the right side of `=`, did not see that he's modifying `z` twice!!!

Comment: You are definitely right about UB with the assignment to `z`. However, even with no assignment of `z` the result remains the same ([demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/zR0EOl)).

Comment: When x is `1` in the beginning, the subexpression `++z` is not evaluated, therefore no UB.

Comment: @Cubbi, I believe you misunderstand UB. The compiler doesn't necessarily _know_ the value of `x` at the expression start. It's therefore free to generate whatever code it wants in response to badly formed source, even going so far as to do nothing, or set all variables to 42. UB doesn't become defined simply because the data being fed into an expression changes. The _probabilities_ of certain errant behaviour may be low but _possibilities_ are not limited in any way (as per C99 3.4.3/2).

Comment: In other words, undefined means **undefined**, not "less defined" :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I disagree: it doesn't say that an expression that may potentially break the rules is undefined; it says that `by the evaluation of an expression` (C99). No evaluation, no UB.

Comment: @Cubbi, actually, you appear to be right on that point. It's the evaluation of the subexpression combined with assignment that causes UB. Though the answer is still correct (my "brainfart" was in a comment), I'll adjust it to make that clear.

Comment: Both the || and && operators force left-to-right evaluation, *and* both introduce sequence points; there is no undefined behavior here.

Comment: @JohnBode, the sequence point for &&/|| is after the _first_ expression, there is none between the _second_ expression and the assignment. Hence `z = a && ++z;` will be UB if `a` is nonzero.