# Output of the following C program

Tags: c

What should be the output of this C program?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  int x,y,z;
  x=y=z=1;
  z = ++x || ++y && ++z;
  printf("x=%d y=%d z=%d\n",x,y,z);
  return 0;
}
```

The given output is : 
x=2 y=1 z=1
I understand the output for x, but fail to see how y and z values don't get incremented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "++x || ++y && ++z" calculate "++x" first, even though operator "&&" has higher precedence than "||"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700352/why-does-x-y-z-calculate-x-first-even-though-operator-ha)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a result of [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

The expression `++x` evaluates to `2`, and the compiler knows that `2 || anything` always evaluates to `1` ("true") no matter what `anything` is. Therefore it does not proceed to evaluate `anything` and the values of `y` and `z` do not change.

If you try with

```
x=-1;
y=z=1;
```

You will see that `y` and `z` *will* be incremented, because the compiler has to evaluate the right hand side of the OR to determine the result of the expression.

**Edit:** asaerl answered your follow-up question in the comments first so I 'll just expand on his correct answer a little.

Operator precedence determines how the parts that make up an expression bind together. Because AND has higher precedence than OR, the compiler knows that you wrote

```
++x || (++y && ++z)
```

instead of

```
(++x || ++y) && ++z
```

This leaves it tasked to do an OR between `++x` and `++y && ++z`. At this point it would normally be free to select if it would "prefer" to evaluate one or the other expression first -- as per the standard -- and you would not normally be able to depend on the specific order. This order has nothing to do with operator precedence.

However, specifically for `||` and `&&` the standard demands that evaluation will *always* proceed from left to right so that short-circuiting can work and developers can *depend* on the rhs expression not being evaluated if the result of evaluating the lhs tells.

Comment: Thanks that helped, but doesn't the order of precedence come into play here? Meaning the ++y && ++z should be evaluated first, before the || ?

Comment: No. precedence is order in parsing, not order of evaluating.
BTW, if `++z` was been evaluated, it was UB. (changing `z` twice)

Answer (score 1):

In C, any thing other than 0 is treated as true, And the evaluation for the || start from left to right.

Hence the compiler will check first left operand and if it is true then the compiler will not check other operands. 
ex. A || B  - In this case if A is true then compiler will return true only, and will not check whether B is true or False. But if A is false then it will check B and return accordingly means if B is true then will return true or if B is false then it will return false.

In your program compiler first will check ++x(i.e 2) and anything other than 0 is true in C. Hence it will not check/increment other expressions.