# Shortcircuiting of AND in case of increment / decrement operator

Tags: c, logical-operators, short-circuiting

In the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     int a = 1;
     int b = 1;
     int c = a || --b;
     int d = a-- && --b;
     printf("a = %d, b = %d, c = %d, d = %d", a, b, c, d);
     return 0;
}
```

i was expecting the output to be:

> a=0,b=1,c=1,d=0

because due to short circuiting in the line below, ie a-- returns 0 so the other part wont get executed right?

```
int d = a-- && --b;
```

The output is:

> a = 0, b = 0, c = 1, d = 0

can anyone please explain?

Comment: `a--` evaluates to `a`, in this case `1` and then decrements `a`.

Comment: [Why does `++x || ++y && ++z` calculate `++x` first, even though operator `&&` has higher precedence than `||`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3700352/995714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int c = a || --b;
```

In this line, the C standard **requires** the C implementation to evaluate `a` first and, if it is not zero, **not to evaluate** `--b`. Although `--` has higher precedence than `||`, that just means that `--` is grouped with `b` for the purposes of determining the structure of the expression, not for purposes of evaluating it. The left side of an `||` operator **must** be evaluated before the right side and, if the left side is true, the right side **must not** be evaluated, even in part.

So, after the above, `b` is not changed; it is still 1.

```
int d = a-- && --b;
```

As with `||`, the left-hand side of the `&&` is evaluated first. So `a--` is evaluated. This changes `a` to 0. However, the value of `a--` is `a` before the change, so it is 1. A value of 0 would prevent the right side from being evaluated (because, once we know the left side is zero, we know the value of the complete `&&` expression is zero). But, since the left side is not zero, `--b` must be evaluated to finish the `&&`. This changes `b` to 0. “Short-circuiting” means the left side is evaluated **first**, but the right side is still evaluated when necessary.

Comment: Yeah - when i had posted my answer - i completely overlooked the fact that there are sequence points `Between evaluation of the left and right operands of the && (logical AND), || (logical OR) (as part of short-circuit evaluation), and comma operators`

Answer (score 5):

In first case

```
int c = a || --b;
```

After this `a=1` , `b=1` and `c=1`

`a` value is `1` , because of short circuit evaluation `--b` did not performed

```
int d = a-- && --b;
```

`a--`  is `post decrement` so decrement of `a` won't effect in expression 
where as `--b` is `pre decrement` so effects here

Your condition becomes

```
   int d= 1 && 0 ;
```

After this `a=0;` , `b=0`,`c=1` and `d=0`.

Comment: I don't understand why your answer was downvoted (same for my answer). So, +1.

Comment: thanks for upvote. I did not explained clearly to be frank. I was explained wrongly.

Comment: @Maxime: It was voted down because it was initially wrong; it stated that `--b` executes first. It has been edited since then.

Comment: @niko thanks for downvote,  I deserve that. it helps me to correct my answer.

Answer (score 4):

In the first **or** operation, `--b` is not executed since `a` equals 1:

```
int c = a || --b;
```

But `b` is decremented here:

```
int d = a-- && --b;
```

Because `a` equals 1 and is decremented after it is evaluated (`a--` equals 1). In other words, this line is similar to:

```
int d = 1 && --b;
```

`b` was equal to 1 so now `b` equals 0 now. And `d` also equals 0 because `--b` returns 0.

Comment: could you tell me why b is still 0 why does not it turn to -1? .

Comment: @nico b equals 1 at this moment. That's why. I'll edit to explain the previous line too.

Answer (score 2):

> the line below, ie `a--` returns 0

No, it doesn't. It yields 1, as the post-decrement operator evaluates to the unmodified value of the variable. What you are thinking about is perhaps `--a`.

Comment: At first attempt `1 -- the po`  was confusing to me

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Fair enough. I've re-worded it.

Comment: Your answer did not satisfy us.. could you make more clear explaination

Comment: @niko what else do you need?

Answer (score 1):

`c = a || --b`

so at first `a is evaluated` and `a` value is `1` which is `true`. So compiler does not evaluate `--b`. So `b` value is still `1`

Now

`d = a-- && --b`

`a-- && --b` => `1 && 0` (since `--b = 0` ) since `b` value is at `1`.

why `1 because a-- is post decrement operator`

Why `0 because --b is pre decrement operator`

so 1 && 0 returns 0 and this value is stored in d

So the output:  `a = 0, b = 0, c = 1, d = 0`

Comment: There is no associativity here. Left-to-right associativity means that `a || b || c` is grouped as `(a || b) || c`. It does not mean `a` is evaluated before `b`. That is a separate rule.

Answer (score -2):

You're mixing up `a--` with `--a`. The result of the expression `a--` is `a` *before* the decrement, while `--a` is `a` *after* the decrement; in other words:

```
int a = 1;
int b = a--; // b == a == 1
int c = --b; // c == b-1 == 0
```

As a result, you have:

```
int d = a-- && --b;
// =>   1   && b-1
// =>   1   && 0
// =>   0
```

Comment: There is no `int b = a--;` in the original code, and `--b` is not evaluated in the assignment to `c` in the original code.

Comment: I wasn't trying to copy his code there. I thought that was obvious, but w/e.