# Why does the compiler skip some parts of a compound statement

Tags: c++, pre-increment

For example in the code below

```
int x,y,z;
x=y=z=1;
z = ++x && ++y || ++z;
cout<<x<<y<<z;
```

The  output is 2 2 1. 
I guess it is because compiler knew that '++x && ++y' gives a 'true', so it skipped the remaining line `|| ++z`.

However, if I replace it with the code below:

```
z = ++x && ++y && ++z;
```

the output is still 2 2 1.
shouldn't it be 2 2 2, because all parts of ANDs '++x' , '++y' , '++z' has to be evaluated.

Comment: nope, `++x && ++y` is still true, so `++z` is not evaluated.

Comment: I really don't get what you're asking for?!? Elaborate please! ...

Comment: I don't see the reason for the downvotes - this is a common mistake regarding accidental type-switching.

Comment: BTW, this is undefined behavior. (`z` is modified more than once between sequence points.)

Comment: @n00dle it's so common that it has at least 10384762488575 individual answers and duplicates all around Stack Overflow. There's no point in asking it *yet another time.*

Comment: @user3477950 In which case why did none of the downvoters add a useful comment to show one of the duplicate answers?

Comment: duplicate of [Why does “++x || ++y && ++z” calculate “++x” first, even though operator “&&” has higher precedence than “||”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3700352/995714)

Answer (score 1):

> I guess it is because compiler knew that '++x && ++y' gives a 'true', so it skipped the remaining line '|| ++z'.

That's correct. It's not necessarily done at compile time though, it could be performed at run time in a more complex situation (as the compiler can't guarantee to know the values within each variable.

That's not why `z == 1` though.

You're setting `z = ++x && ++y && ++z`, which implicitly casts the boolean produced by the `&&` to an integer. The integer representation of the boolean `true` is `1`, therefore `z == 1`.

Comment: It could be done at compile-time; it's an easy optimization given that x, y and z are set just before the statement. And afaik, it is still UB, so the value of z at the end is unspecified.

Comment: Fair enough that is true for this toy example, I was thinking in the general case. I'll add "necessarily" :) It is UB, but in this case, is my suggestion not the logical answer?

Comment: It's certainly the boolean answer :) It's probably the explanation, but it still cannot be relied upon to always work. (Not my downvote, by the way.)