# please help me out with the working of the c program

Tags: c

```
int x = 1,y = 1,z = 1;

++x || ++y && ++z;

printf("%d%d%d",x,y,z);
```

it is giving the output of 2,1,1. But how these unary operators and logical operators are working to give such a result i cant understand. Whether only unary operator working only for first case and not for others. C doesnot ave any boolean datatype also. Please help me with my problem.

Comment: In `C`, if you have `exp1 || exp2` and `exp1` is "truthy" (which `2` is truthy), then it won't bother executing `exp2` since `||` means OR. Operator precedence dictates that `++x||++y&&++z` will behave as `++x||(++y&&++z)`. So only `x` will be incremented. The expression `++y&&++z` is skipped.

Comment: duplicate of [Why does `++x || ++y && ++z` calculate `++x` first, even though operator `&&` has higher precedence than `||`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3700352/995714)

Answer (score 1):

[lurker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980550/lurker)'s answer above is correct.

`||` and `&&` are [short circuit operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Equivalent code is:

```
if(! ++x ) {
    if( ++y ) {
        ++z;
    } 
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for clearing the doubt